# User control - Pick value of property from a list of property names of the data source

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I created a `UserControl` with a property called `DataSource`. The code is like this:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private object MyDataSource;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
    [TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceConverter, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
    [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataSourceListEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
    public object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return MyDataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (MyDataSource != value)
                MyDataSource = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can select the value for `DataSource` property from a drop down list in design time as image shows:

[image: DataSource property in properties pan]

Now what I exactly want is another property called `DataColumn` that when `DataSource` has been set  to a `DataTable` , user can select one of that DataTable's columns from a drop down list in properties pan in design time for "DataColumn" property value.Obviously when DataSource has been changed values in DataColumn's drop down list must be changed accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decorate your property with following attributes:

```
[DefaultValue("")]
[TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldConverter, System.Design")]
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldEditor, System.Design",
    typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public string DataColumn{ get; set; }
```

In above code, `DataMemberFieldEditor` is responsible for showing the drop-down containing property names to pick.

Also `DataMemberFieldConverter` is responsible to convert `None` to empty string when you pick `None` from drop-down.

This is the way that [`DisplayMember`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,1d55d91a8ec5140a) property of `ListControl` works. You can take a look at its [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,1d55d91a8ec5140a).

Comment: Thanks for answering. This shows the property as like as i want. but how can i fill combo box with correct values according to DataSource?

Comment: It's enough to choose the value of `DataSource` property first and then select value of `DataColumn` property form drop-down.

Comment: This is the way that [`DisplayMember`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,1d55d91a8ec5140a) property of `ListControl` works. You can take a look at its [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,1d55d91a8ec5140a).